# Can't get the URI from a URL that contains parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

So, when I try to get the URI String(echo $this->uri->segment(2);) for thsi URL: http://example.com/first-uri/6, I get "6" so no problem there, but the same request made to the follosing URL (that has parameters):http://example.com/first-uri?parameter1=x&parameter2=y/6 does return anything.

Any ideas?

Thank You

Comment: use $this->input->get('parameter1') .

Comment: did you change $config['enable_query_strings'] to true

Comment: yup! that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use

```
//print_r($_REQUEST); 

echo $_REQUEST['parameter1']; //$this->input->get('parameter1')
echo $_REQUEST['parameter2'];//$this->input->get('parameter2')
```

Comment: ..no, I'm trying to get the second URI, in this case 6, not the parameters. It only works for an URL without parametes.

Comment: once print the array //print_r($_REQUEST);

Answer (score 0):

First your  **form method should be POST type** `<form method='post'>` . Or you have to use $this->input->get('parameter');